# Mobile Redirect

Tags: 7, redirection, theming

So I need to set up mobile redirect for a Drupal 7 site I've been working on, but there are some conditions and I can't quite decide what the best route would be. Basically, if the user is browsing the site on mobile, we need to redirect to m.example.com - However, we also want this to NOT happen if the user is browsing within the "Events" section of our site "example.com/events," but there is also a link ON the mobile site to view the full page and redirects to "example.com/?nomobile=true" and if the user follows this link we want to break the redirect

Given these conditions, does anyone know the best course of action? Whether it's a module that can be configured (Simple Mobile Redirect doesn't seem to be flexible enough to handle all of this), or some kind of PHP code - I tried doing this with JavaScript but the redirect just doesn't seem to fire (even though the console.logs within the function are returned, so I don't think that will work.)

Much appreciated

Comment: Whoops, ignore this, it turns out the JavaScript actually is working but wasn't originally due to some kind of cache setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Context module will allow you to create contexts and set reactions for each context.

A context can be anything:

- User has this role
- The page is a taxonomy term page
- The visitor is using a mobile

You will need these modules:

- [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context)
- [Context Mobile Detect](http://drupal.org/project/context_mobile_detect)

---

Another option is to use the **Omega Theme** which is a fully featured responsive base theme, it looks a little bit complicated at first but [the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/819164) is excellent.

**PS:** You will still use the Context module, you can find how on the documentation.